# Sorting by similar numeric value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

Lets imagine simple elastic documents like this:

```
{
 title: 'Samsung Galaxy S5' //string
 price 599.45 //float
},
{
 title: 'Cover for Samsung Galaxy S5'
 price: 5.49
}
```

Now I want to write bool query that will take some title and some price, like so: (I use ruflin/elastica)

```
$query = [
            'from' => 0,
            'size' => 1000,
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        ['match' => ['title' => $title]],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

So this works kind of fine. But one thing I would like to add, is some way of prioritizing items that are most similar in price.

In this case it will work fine. But if there was to be many thousands of products, I would like that firstly I would get to see results that are similar in prices. I do not want to use a filter as it would potentially exclude good hits, and in my particular use case false positives is acceptable, while false negatives are not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "similar in price", please!

Comment: well in index we have 2 prices (599.45 and 5.49). So if we search by price 500. Well most 'similar' price out of two is 599.45. Well maybe word 'similar'  is not the greatest choice in this case. Maybe nearest or something like that.

Comment: Nearest from mathematical point of view (range queries) or nearest from text analysis point of view (fuzzy queries)?

Comment: Mathematical would be preferable, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a `function_score` with a `decay` function. Basically, is like a `range` query, but the edges are not so strict, meaning the closer the value is to the "origin" value (the one you are searching for) the better the score is. So, it's not a black/white situation but "shades of gray" comparison. More details about this here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay

And a query that you can start playing with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "title": "samsung"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "exp": {
            "price": {
              "origin": "500",
              "scale": "100",
              "decay": 0.5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Sounds like something very much like what I am looking for. Will try this, and accept the answer soon :)